# Evaluating Definite Integrals: $ \int_{-2}^{0} \ (\frac14{t^5}+\frac1 5{t^4}-t) dt$

Tags: calculus

$$ \int_{-2}^{0} \ (\frac14{t^5}+\frac1 5{t^4}-t) dt$$

My answer is -368/600

[image]

Comment: You just want to know if your calculation is right: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F4t%5E5%2B1%2F5t%5E4-t+from+-2+to+0)

Comment: Well it is wrong. The computer program has already told me so. I'd like to know where I went wrong with answer,.

Comment: Maybe if you wrote out your integration. We could see more clearly where you went astray.

Comment: E: Misread your result

Comment: The unreduced fraction is correct, but wrong sign.

Comment: Evaluate at the upper limit, then minus evaluation at the lower limit. The other way around is one way to make this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

$$ \int_{-2}^{0} \ (\frac14{t^5}+\frac1 5{t^4}-t) dt= \frac1 4\int_{-2}^{0}t^5dt+\frac 1 5\int_{-2}^0 t^4dt+(-1)\int_{-2}^0tdt $$

Comment: I have already done that. I want to know if my calculations is right?

Comment: Actually how you wrote the anti-derivative looks wrong.

Comment: Seems wrong in what way? You can easily check your results with Symbolab/wolfram alpha: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%5E%7B0%7D_%7B-2%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B4%7Dt%5E%7B5%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B5%7Dt%5E%7B4%7D-t%5Cright)dt/?origin=enterkey.